# How to separate a view from a controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, controller, mediator

one of my co-workers reviewed my code in javascript and told me that I should not use a view in a controller. Instead, I should use a mediator. I'm totally lost. He will not be available until next week so here I am.

In my applications, I initialize a view in a controller (pseudo code) like below.

```
var controller = (function(){

   return {
      init: function()
      {
          this.view = new View("template");
          this.view.render();
      }
   }

})();
```

I have no idea how I separate a view from a controller and use mediator to work with them.

could anyone please give me an idea or a sample code or concept?

Answer (score 2):

First of all a bit on roles of Ms, Vs & Cs in a MVC pattern:

The three parts:

#### `Model`-View-Controller:

> We will call the unchanging essence of the application/domain, the model (in the singular). In object-oriented terms, this will consist of the set of classes which model and support the underlying problem, and which therefore will tend to be stable and as long-lived as the problem itself.
>   How much should the model (classes) know about the connection to the outside world? Nothing, absolutely nothing.

#### Model-`View`-Controller:

> For a given situation, in a given version there will be one or more interfaces with the model, which we'll call the views (plural).
>   In object-oriented terms, these will consist of sets of classes which give us "windows" (very often actual windows).

#### Model-View-`Controller`:

> A controller is an object that lets you manipulate a view. Over-simplifying a bit, the controller handles the input whilst the view handles the output. Controllers have the most knowledge of platforms and operating systems. Views are fairly independent of whether their event come from Microsoft Windows, X Windows or whatever.

---

What your co-worker is trying to tell you is this:

The below pic is a Sequence Flow(an approximate) pertaining to Zend framework, which is a MVC framework for PHP.

Click [here](http://www.kitpages.fr.s3.amazonaws.com/bundle/kitpagesFileSystem/kitpagesFile/public/18/18/sequence_globale.jpg) for a bigger image.
[image: Zend Framework calls]

Observe the Dispatcher (3rd from last) in the above diagram. 
Lets consider only the following for your case:

> - Front.php      : as your view.
> - Dispatcher    : the mediator your co-worker mentioned.
> - MyController : as your controller.

What you will have to do is this:
If the *View* has to trigger an event, it will not handle the event by itself. It will dispatch the event to the *Dispatcher* along with the parameters (if any) for the event.
 The *Dispatcher* will now

> - Look for the controller that is capable of handling such an event.
> - Create the controller
> - Pass the event to the controller along with the parameters (if any).

The controller will now:

> - Prepare for the event.
> - Execute the event.
> - Return result-set(if any) to *Dispatcher*.

The *Dispatcher* will now:

> - Return the result-set(if any) back to the *View*.

The *View* will now:

> - Render the result-set(if any) and present it.

Why so much needs to be done?

`To keep the roles segregated and clear`.

Comment: ThinkingMonkey // Thank you for the detailed answer. However, I don't see a view in the diagram. Look at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html, scroll down to the ErrorController. It also uses a view inside the controller.

Comment: @moon Yes, there is no view in the diagram. That is why I asked you to consider _front.php_ as a view. There has been a lot of implementation differences when it comes to MVC. (refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692965/what-is-the-actual-pattern-for-mvc-wrt-webapplications) ). If traditional pattern is to be considered, `views know their model but the model doesn't know its views, the controllers knows their views but the view doesn't know its controller.` So what you are doing is not wrong or bad practice.

Comment: @moon Its just a preference of how you want to call a _view_. When answering your question I am just concentrating on _how to separate a view from a controller and use mediator to work with them._

Comment: // I do appreciate your answer, but it still doesn't make sense. As you know, Zend Framework uses an actual view in their controllers just like I did in my pseudo code. Then the question remains, why even Zend Framework uses a view in their controller? which is pretty much the same question I have.

Comment: @moon as I said Its for _separation of concerns_ & that _what you are doing is not wrong or bad practice._. _Mediator_ is just an extra module in your MVC. Your co-worker is probably suggesting this for: he does not want the core files of the app i.e. _Models, View, Controllers_ do not interact directly.

Comment: @moon To put it in better words: _The Controller does not oversee the operation of the Views and Models - it's not a GodClass. The controller mediates communication and unifies validation, using either direct calls or the ObserverPattern._ from: [Cunningham & Cunningham, Inc: Model View Controller.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ModelViewController)

Comment: ThinkingMoney // Thank you for the suggestion, but my question still remains.